# Express3 to Express4 getting error during a app.get route statement

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working my way through Mongoose for App Development. Author used Express 3 during his book, but it should be a easy thing to use Express 4.  I keep getting a app.get method error (app.js line 29).  It should work according to documentation in express 4 website.  Error says requires callback functions but got a [object].  The route file for user is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

// GET user creation form
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    res.render('user-form', {
        title: "Create user",
        buttonText: "Join!"
    });
};
```

and my line 29 in app.js says

```
app.get('/user', user);
```

I used the standard one that comes with express generator and just changed it to agree with my filename.

where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user you're passing to get is not a function, but an object. Since you didn't post the whole code, I can't exactly say what's wrong, but this should give you an idea:

```
var userController = function(req, res) {
    res.render('user-form', {
        title: "Create user",
        buttonText: "Join!"
    });
};

app.get('/user', userController);
```

Based on the code, here's how you can do it.

**user.js**:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

// GET user creation form
module.exports.userController = function(req, res) {
    res.render('user-form', {
        title: "Create user",
        buttonText: "Join!"
    });
};
```

**Router**:

```
var user = require('./user.js'); 
app.get('/user', user.userController);
```

Comment: Ok, now I get it.  I have a git of my project ('training') so far at https://github.com/EnergeticPixels/mongooseAppDev.git

Comment: Thank you @prakharsingh95.  I used your example.  I have some research to accomplish before I feel comfortable using module.exports and when to use it versus just exports.somename.

Answer (score 0):

> Express 4 is a breaking change from Express 3.

So, here's what you need to change in your route file:

`

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model('User');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('user-form', {
        title: "Create user",
        buttonText: "Join!"
    });

module.exports = router;
```

`

and `app.use('/user', user);`

More at: http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html
and there are plenty of express 4 tutorials so use one.

Comment: Thank you @Rahat.  I have some more research to do before I feel comfortable.  Need to research when/how to use module.exports versus just exports.somename.  I found some on SO that I am already mulling over.